# In iOS, how do I create a button that is always on top of all other view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift

No matter if modals are presented or the user performs any type of segue.

Is there a way to keep the button "always on top" (not the top of the screen) throughout the entire app?

Is there any way to make this button draggable and snappable to the screen?

I'm looking at Apple's own Assistive Touch as an example of such button.

Comment: are you asking to constraint the button to top ?

Comment: Whose modals? Where are these modals coming from?

Comment: The modals could be coming from any ViewController who calls them.

Comment: Modals like UIAlertView, modals like the permission request for location access, modals like -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:] ... ?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can do this by creating your own subclass of `UIWindow`, and then creating an instance of that subclass. You'll need to do three things to the window:

1. Set its `windowLevel` to a very high number, like `CGFloat.max`. It's clamped (as of iOS 9.2) to 10000000, but you might as well set it to the highest possible value.
2. Set the window's background color to nil to make it transparent.
3. Override the window's `pointInside(_:withEvent:)` method to return true only for points in the button. This will make the window only accept touches that hit the button, and all other touches will be passed on to other windows.

Then create a root view controller for the window. Create the button and add it to the view hierarchy, and tell the window about it so the window can use it in `pointInside(_:withEvent:)`.

There's one last thing to do. It turns out that the on-screen keyboard also uses the highest window level, and since it might come on the screen after your window does, it will be on top of your window. You can fix that by observing `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and resetting your window's `windowLevel` when that happens (because doing so is documented to put your window on top of all windows at the same level).

Here's a demo. I'll start with the view controller I'm going to use in the window.

```
import UIKit

class FloatingButtonController: UIViewController {
```

Here's the button instance variable. Whoever creates a `FloatingButtonController` can access the button to add a target/action to it. I'll demonstrate that later.

```
    private(set) var button: UIButton!
```

You have to “implement” this initializer, but I'm not going to use this class in a storyboard.

```
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
```

Here's the real initializer.

```
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        window.windowLevel = CGFloat.max
        window.hidden = false
        window.rootViewController = self
```

Setting `window.hidden = false` gets it onto the screen (when the current `CATransaction` commits). I also need to watch for the keyboard to appear:

```
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidShow:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

I need a reference to my window, which will be an instance of a custom class:

```
    private let window = FloatingButtonWindow()
```

I'll create my view hierarchy in code to keep this answer self-contained:

```
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        button.setTitle("Floating", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        button.sizeToFit()
        button.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(10, 10), size: button.bounds.size)
        button.autoresizingMask = []
        view.addSubview(button)
        self.view = view
        self.button = button
        window.button = button
```

Nothing special going on there. I'm just creating my root view and putting a button in it.

To allow the user to drag the button around, I'll add a pan gesture recognizer to the button:

```
        let panner = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panDidFire:")
        button.addGestureRecognizer(panner)
    }
```

The window will lay out its subviews when it first appears, and when it is resized (in particular because of interface rotation), so I'll want to reposition the button at those times:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        snapButtonToSocket()
    }
```

(More on `snapButtonToSocket` shortly.)

To handle dragging the button, I use the pan gesture recognizer in the standard way:

```
    func panDidFire(panner: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let offset = panner.translationInView(view)
        panner.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, inView: view)
        var center = button.center
        center.x += offset.x
        center.y += offset.y
        button.center = center
```

You asked for “snapping”, so if the pan is ending or cancelled, I'll snap the button to one of a fixed number of positions that I call “sockets”:

```
        if panner.state == .Ended || panner.state == .Cancelled {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
                self.snapButtonToSocket()
            }
        }
    }
```

I handle the keyboard notification by resetting `window.windowLevel`:

```
    func keyboardDidShow(note: NSNotification) {
        window.windowLevel = 0
        window.windowLevel = CGFloat.max
    }
```

To snap the button to a socket, I find the nearest socket to the button's position and move the button there. Note that this isn't necessarily what you want on an interface rotation, but I'll leave a more perfect solution as an exercise for the reader. At any rate it keeps the button on the screen after a rotation.

```
    private func snapButtonToSocket() {
        var bestSocket = CGPoint.zero
        var distanceToBestSocket = CGFloat.infinity
        let center = button.center
        for socket in sockets {
            let distance = hypot(center.x - socket.x, center.y - socket.y)
            if distance < distanceToBestSocket {
                distanceToBestSocket = distance
                bestSocket = socket
            }
        }
        button.center = bestSocket
    }
```

I put a socket in each corner of the screen, and one in the middle for demonstration purposes:

```
    private var sockets: [CGPoint] {
        let buttonSize = button.bounds.size
        let rect = view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4 + buttonSize.width / 2, dy: 4 + buttonSize.height / 2)
        let sockets: [CGPoint] = [
            CGPointMake(rect.minX, rect.minY),
            CGPointMake(rect.minX, rect.maxY),
            CGPointMake(rect.maxX, rect.minY),
            CGPointMake(rect.maxX, rect.maxY),
            CGPointMake(rect.midX, rect.midY)
        ]
        return sockets
    }

}
```

Finally, the custom `UIWindow` subclass:

```
private class FloatingButtonWindow: UIWindow {

    var button: UIButton?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        backgroundColor = nil
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

As I mentioned, I need to override `pointInside(_:withEvent:)` so that the window ignores touches outside the button:

```
    private override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        guard let button = button else { return false }
        let buttonPoint = convertPoint(point, toView: button)
        return button.pointInside(buttonPoint, withEvent: event)
    }

}
```

Now how do you use this thing? I downloaded [Apple's AdaptivePhotos sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AdaptivePhotos/Introduction/Intro.html) and added my `FloatingButtonController.swift` file to the `AdaptiveCode` target. I added a property to `AppDelegate`:

```
var floatingButtonController: FloatingButtonController?
```

Then I added code to the end of `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` to create a `FloatingButtonController`:

```
    floatingButtonController = FloatingButtonController()
    floatingButtonController?.button.addTarget(self, action: "floatingButtonWasTapped", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Those lines go right before the `return true` at the end of the function. I also need to write the action method for the button:

```
func floatingButtonWasTapped() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Don't do that!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Sorry…", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

That's all I had to do. But I did one more thing for demonstration purposes: in AboutViewController, I changed `label` to a `UITextView` so I'd have a way to bring up the keyboard.

Here's what the button looks like:

[image: dragging the button]

Here's the effect of tapping the button. Notice that the button floats above the alert:

[image: clicking the button]

Here's what happens when I bring up the keyboard:

[image: keyboard]

Does it handle rotation? You bet:

[image: rotation]

Well, the rotation-handling isn't perfect, because which socket is nearest the button after a rotation may not be the same “logical” socket as before the rotation. You could fix this by keeping track of which socket the button was last snapped to, and handling a rotation specially (by detecting the size change).

I put the entire `FloatingViewController.swift` in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/ea37ee75a87efab5d7e8) for your convenience.

Comment: Actually, a look at the [*View Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH4-SW13) has made me think you probably also want to observe `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` and reset `window.windowLevel` when you get one.

Comment: Great explanation. Can you provide the objective-C version too @rob?

Comment: Directly to quote Apple: "To change the content your app displays, you can change the window’s root view; *you don’t create a new window.*"; "Most iOS applications create and use only one window during their lifetime. ... However, if an application supports the use of an external display for video out, it can create an additional window ... All other windows are typically created by the system"; etc, etc. Like every third-party attempt at a UIAlertView workalike (before Apple decided that being window-level modal was a broken pattern), expect this approach to break regularly.

Comment: The [`UIWindow` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow?preferredLanguage=occ#) has been updated to clarify whether it's acceptable to create multiple windows. It now says “Create additional windows (as needed) to display additional content”, “You can create additional windows and display them on the device’s main screen”, and “you can also display multiple windows on the same screen”. See also WWDC 2016 Session 601 (“Go Live with ReplayKit”), in which an Apple engineer walks through creating a second window.

Comment: Can you provide the objective-C version too

Comment: That's not something I want to spend time on. If you are familiar with UIKit, converting the code to Objective-C should be easy even if you don't know Swift.

Comment: Can you please also add the AppDelegateCode? It will be helpful.

Comment: This is a BEAUTIFUL answer. Very impressive!

Comment: While this work very good for the purpose of  a "floating button". There's one issue I'm struggling with: `preferredStatusBarStyle` is always taken from the "top" window's rootViewController. This solution makes it always the same, which look strange in some situations. For example the background of modals in iOS 13 needs `.lightContent` while my root view (UITabBarController) needs `darkContent`. Otherwise it looks buggy. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Great answer. How does the window actually get attached to the current windows array? I can't see how this happens from your answer.

Comment: I mentioned in the answer that “Setting `window.hidden = false` gets it onto the screen (when the current `CATransaction` commits).” That also adds it to `UIApplication.shared.windows`.

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 3:

```
import UIKit

private class FloatingButtonWindow: UIWindow {
    var button: UIButton?

    var floatingButtonController: FloatingButtonController?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        backgroundColor = nil
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    fileprivate override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        guard let button = button else { return false }
        let buttonPoint = convert(point, to: button)
        return button.point(inside: buttonPoint, with: event)
    }
}

class FloatingButtonController: UIViewController {
    private(set) var button: UIButton!

    private let window = FloatingButtonWindow()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        window.windowLevel = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        window.isHidden = false
        window.rootViewController = self
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardDidShow(note: NSNotification) {
        window.windowLevel = 0
        window.windowLevel = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Floating", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        button.sizeToFit()
        button.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10), size: button.bounds.size)
        button.autoresizingMask = []
        view.addSubview(button)
        self.view = view
        self.button = button
        window.button = button


        let panner = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panDidFire))
        button.addGestureRecognizer(panner)
    }

    func panDidFire(panner: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let offset = panner.translation(in: view)
        panner.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
        var center = button.center
        center.x += offset.x
        center.y += offset.y
        button.center = center

        if panner.state == .ended || panner.state == .cancelled {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.snapButtonToSocket()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        snapButtonToSocket()
    }

    private var sockets: [CGPoint] {
        let buttonSize = button.bounds.size
        let rect = view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4 + buttonSize.width / 2, dy: 4 + buttonSize.height / 2)
        let sockets: [CGPoint] = [
            CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY),
            CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY),
            CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY),
            CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY),
            CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        ]
        return sockets
    }

    private func snapButtonToSocket() {
        var bestSocket = CGPoint.zero
        var distanceToBestSocket = CGFloat.infinity
        let center = button.center
        for socket in sockets {
            let distance = hypot(center.x - socket.x, center.y - socket.y)
            if distance < distanceToBestSocket {
                distanceToBestSocket = distance
                bestSocket = socket
            }
        }
        button.center = bestSocket
    }
}
```

And in AppDelegate:

```
    var floatingButtonController: FloatingButtonController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

     floatingButtonController = FloatingButtonController()
     floatingButtonController?.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AppDelegate.floatingButtonWasTapped), for: .touchUpInside)


    return true
}

func floatingButtonWasTapped() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Don't do that!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Sorry…", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: how to dimiss this window ?

Comment: @Abhishek `floatingButtonController.isHidden = true` is one way

Answer (score 8):

## **Swift 4.2 - UIViewController extension**

A modified version of Rob Mayoff's answer for local floating buttons.

UIViewController extension may provide you a better control over floating button. However it will be added on a single view controller which you call **addFloatingButton** instead of all view controllers..

- Adding floating button in a specific view controller enables to add view controller specific actions to floating button.
- It won't block the **topViewController** function if you use it frequently. (It is provided below)
- If you use the floating button to toggle support chat for your application(for example Zendesk Chat API), UIViewController extension method provides you a better control over navigation between view controllers.

> For this question, this might not be the best practice however, with
>   this type control over floating button should enable different
>   practices for different purposes.

### UIViewController Extension

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var floatingButton: UIButton?
    }

    var floatingButton: UIButton? {
        get {
            guard let value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.floatingButton) as? UIButton else {return nil}
            return value
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.floatingButton, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }

    func addFloatingButton() {
        // Customize your own floating button UI
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        let image = UIImage(named: "tab_livesupport_unselected")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.obiletGreen
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.12
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        button.sizeToFit()
        let buttonSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
        let rect = UIScreen.main.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4 + buttonSize.width / 2, dy: 4 + buttonSize.height / 2)
        button.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - 15, y: rect.maxY - 50), size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
        // button.cornerRadius = 30 -> Will destroy your shadows, however you can still find workarounds for rounded shadow.
        button.autoresizingMask = []
        view.addSubview(button)
        floatingButton = button
        let panner = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panDidFire(panner:)))
        floatingButton?.addGestureRecognizer(panner)
        snapButtonToSocket()
    }

    @objc fileprivate func panDidFire(panner: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let floatingButton = floatingButton else {return}
        let offset = panner.translation(in: view)
        panner.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
        var center = floatingButton.center
        center.x += offset.x
        center.y += offset.y
        floatingButton.center = center

        if panner.state == .ended || panner.state == .cancelled {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.snapButtonToSocket()
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func snapButtonToSocket() {
        guard let floatingButton = floatingButton else {return}
        var bestSocket = CGPoint.zero
        var distanceToBestSocket = CGFloat.infinity
        let center = floatingButton.center
        for socket in sockets {
            let distance = hypot(center.x - socket.x, center.y - socket.y)
            if distance < distanceToBestSocket {
                distanceToBestSocket = distance
                bestSocket = socket
            }
        }
        floatingButton.center = bestSocket
    }

    fileprivate var sockets: [CGPoint] {
        let buttonSize = floatingButton?.bounds.size ?? CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        let rect = view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4 + buttonSize.width / 2, dy: 4 + buttonSize.height / 2)
        let sockets: [CGPoint] = [
            CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 15, y: rect.minY + 30),
            CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 15, y: rect.maxY - 50),
            CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - 15, y: rect.minY + 30),
            CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - 15, y: rect.maxY - 50)
        ]
        return sockets
    }
    // Custom socket position to hold Y position and snap to horizontal edges.
    // You can snap to any coordinate on screen by setting custom socket positions.
    fileprivate var horizontalSockets: [CGPoint] {
        guard let floatingButton = floatingButton else {return []}
        let buttonSize = floatingButton.bounds.size
        let rect = view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4 + buttonSize.width / 2, dy: 4 + buttonSize.height / 2)
        let y = min(rect.maxY - 50, max(rect.minY + 30, floatingButton.frame.minY + buttonSize.height / 2))
        let sockets: [CGPoint] = [
            CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 15, y: y),
            CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - 15, y: y)
        ]
        return sockets
    }
}
```

### UIViewController Usage

> I prefer to add floating button after viewDidLoad(_ animated:). 
>   It may need to call **bringSubviewToFront()** if another subview blocks the floating button afterwards.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        addFloatingButton()
        floatingButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(floatingButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func floatingButtonPressed(){
        print("Floating button tapped")
    }
```

### UIApplication - Top View Controller

```
extension UIApplication{

    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Comment: Great job, but I want the button to stop in the middle of Y axis.
Right now it just sticks to the bottoms of the screen.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Thanks, you can change the sockets position to stop the button in the middle of Y axis. I will add a custom socket positions as a guide -> Named as **horizontalSockets**

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot.

Comment: floatingButton?.setTitle("Title", for: .normal) does not work. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's intention in this case would be that your root view controller contain the button and whatever touch logic you want, and that it also embed as a child view controller whatever runs the rest of the app. You are not intended to talk to `UIWindow` directly, and are likely to hit a whole bunch of issues with things like autorotation across versions of iOS if you do.

Old code may still manage to present modals on top using deprecated classes like `UIAlertView`. Apple has explicitly switched to approaches like `UIAlertController` where the thing that is covered explicitly owns the thing that is covering it in order to allow proper view controller containment. You should probably just make the same assumption and decline to use components that sit upon deprecated code.

Comment: I have a blankViewController with a Container View that fills the whole screen. The container view embeds a tabBarViewController (which is my main app).  I created a view in the blankViewController, and it stays. However, anytime there is a modal, it covers the view.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Paramount](https://github.com/onmyway133/Paramount), which basically uses another `UIWindow` to display your button

```
Manager.action = {
  print("action touched")
}

Manager.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

iOS 13+ SceneDelegate version:

```
import UIKit

class FloatingButtonController: UIViewController {

    private(set) var button: UIButton!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    init(scene: UIWindowScene) {
        window = FloatingButtonWindow(scene: scene)
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        window.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        window.isHidden = false
        window.rootViewController = self

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(note:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    }

    private let window: FloatingButtonWindow

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Floating", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        button.sizeToFit()
        button.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10), size: button.bounds.size)
        button.autoresizingMask = []
        view.addSubview(button)
        self.view = view
        self.button = button
        window.button = button

        let panner = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panDidFire(panner:)))
        button.addGestureRecognizer(panner)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        snapButtonToSocket()
    }

    @objc func panDidFire(panner: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let offset = panner.translation(in: view)
        panner.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
        var center = button.center
        center.x += offset.x
        center.y += offset.y
        button.center = center

        if panner.state == .ended || panner.state == .cancelled {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.snapButtonToSocket()
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardDidShow(note: NSNotification) {
        window.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: 0)
        window.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    }

    private func snapButtonToSocket() {
        var bestSocket = CGPoint.zero
        var distanceToBestSocket = CGFloat.infinity
        let center = button.center
        for socket in sockets {
            let distance = hypot(center.x - socket.x, center.y - socket.y)
            if distance < distanceToBestSocket {
                distanceToBestSocket = distance
                bestSocket = socket
            }
        }
        button.center = bestSocket
    }

    private var sockets: [CGPoint] {
        let buttonSize = button.bounds.size
        let rect = view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4 + buttonSize.width / 2, dy: 4 + buttonSize.height / 2)
        let sockets: [CGPoint] = [
            CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY),
            CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY),
            CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY),
            CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY),
            CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        ]
        return sockets
    }

}

private class FloatingButtonWindow: UIWindow {

    var button: UIButton?

    init(scene: UIWindowScene) {
        super.init(windowScene: scene)
        backgroundColor = nil
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    fileprivate override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        guard let button = button else { return false }
        let buttonPoint = convert(point, to: button)
        return button.point(inside: buttonPoint, with: event)
    }

}
```

in SceneDelegate:

```
var floatingButtonController: FloatingButtonController?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    floatingButtonController = FloatingButtonController(scene: scene)
    floatingButtonController?.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(floatingButtonWasTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `zPosition` property of the view's layer (it's a `CALayer` object) to change the z-index of the view, **also you need to add this button or your view as subview of your window not as subview of your any other viewcontrollers**, its default value is 0. But you can change it like this:

```
yourButton.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

You need to import the QuartzCore framework to access the layer. Just add this line of code at the top of your implementation file.

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes the button appear all the time but in some scenarios becomes not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Present it on this:

```
public static var topMostVC: UIViewController? {
    var presentedVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    while let pVC = presentedVC?.presentedViewController {
        presentedVC = pVC
    }

    if presentedVC == nil {
        print("EZSwiftExtensions Error: You don't have any views set. You may be calling them in viewDidLoad. Try viewDidAppear instead.")
    }
    return presentedVC
}

topMostVC?.presentViewController(myAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

//or

let myView = UIView()
topMostVC?.view?.addSubview(myView)
```

These are included as a standard function in a project of mine: https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Comment: If you are going to post links to your own GitHub projects, you should let people know that it's yours. Otherwise you run the danger of having your posts marked as spam.

Comment: I forgot about this one, feel free to edit them if you see posts like this.

Answer (score 1):

**For Objective-c**

To use the FloatingButtonController class in an AppDelegate in objetive-c, simply do the following

A variable of type FloatingButtonController is declared

```
FloatingButtonController *flotatingButton;
```

then in the following added methods

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        flotatingButton = [[FloatingButtonController alloc] init];
        [flotatingButton addTargetWithTarget:self selector:@selector(floatingButtonDidReceiveTouchUpInside)];
}
```

and later the method is created which was added to the button action

```
- (void)floatingButtonDidReceiveTouchUpInside {
    logsView = [ModulosApp supportLogWithDate:[NSDate date]];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER animated:YES completion:nil];
    
    }
```

this way we can use the class in swift calling it from the AppDelegate in objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Add button on UIWindow , it will float on all views in app