# How to create a floating button like Google Map Bottom View in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currenly developing a screen similar to Google Map's bottom view:

[image]

I have created a UIViewController that displays the map and handles the markers on the map. When a user taps on a marker, a bottom view appears partially as shown in Google Maps app. The bottom view is added as a subview and appears partially with animation when a marker is tapped.

I wanted to create a floating button like the one in the picture, so I added a UIButton and its origin.y = -(button.height / 2) so it floats with its midY on the edge of the view. The problem is the button's half is disappeared and not floating on the view. I've researched solutions and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777558/in-ios-how-do-i-create-a-button-that-is-always-on-top-of-all-other-view-control), I'm wondering if this is the best solution, or there is a simpler one.

Note: the button moves with the bottom view when it's dragged upward and becomes a full view.

Comment: Make sure the bottom views `clipsToBounds` property is set to false.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup I did, it's still not showing the button

Comment: Well it's not ideal but you could always make it a separate view and a child of the main view.