# Always on top (on other apps) button in iOS

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development and wondering if it's possible to create a floating button which always stays on top of screen even if you have any other app running in full screen mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In iOS, how do I create a button that is always on top of all other view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777558/in-ios-how-do-i-create-a-button-that-is-always-on-top-of-all-other-view-control)

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that on iOS, Apple isn't allowing this kind of features (like Messenger on Android for example)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean something closer to AssistiveTouch. When turned on in accessibility, it will stay on top of the screen, no matter what app you have open. I recommend reading the Apple Docs for further investigating into this, but at the moment, Apple does not let you do this. Your app can't mess with other apps. It's pretty against what Apple's design guidelines allow you to do.

Is there a work around for what you are trying to accomplish with this? Maybe if you expand your question, I can help.

Comment: Yeah Something similar to AssistiveTouch but with different actions like firing a tap event for instance with some user input. I want to use that button on top of other app running in full screen to and want to pass thru those event to already running app.