# Xcode PDFKit: How To Close PDF File

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdfkit

I have built an App an I'm about to finish my project.

And I need to put a imprint as a pdf-file in my App (legal reasons), which I thought would be no problem.
But I can't figure out what I need to do to get a Close Button to just close the PDF File..

My code:

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {

    let pdfView = PDFView()

    pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(pdfView)

    pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant:25).isActive = true
    pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ImpressumDatenschutz", withExtension: "pdf") else { return }

    if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
        pdfView.document = document
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any other option than putting a button in the upper left corner with a segue that goes back to the page that was open before the PDF was opened. I guess that is good enough for the beginning.

```
@IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "impressumToFirstVC", sender: self)        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a floating button from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159701/2564702) and remove your pdfView by adding `pdfView.removeFromSuperview()` in the floating button action method.

Answer (score -1):

Simple remove from its superview like below:

```
pdfView.removeFromSuperview()
```