# Floating button is not always visible on top

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I had created a floating button so that it can be always shown to the user on the top, but when ever I present a controller using the `UINavigationController` initiated, it hide behinds the presented view

I have a solution but it has to be implemented on every presented view controller.

I created a function by which I'm moving it to front, but for this I need to add code on every presented view controller. Is there any solution to do it a better way?

```
@objcMembers
final class MenuFloatingButton: UIView
{
static let tagValue = 99988


init(exitGuideTourButtonY: CGFloat)
{
    let calculatedFrame = CGRect(x: ExitTourButtonConstant.leftPadding, y: exitGuideTourButtonY, width: ExitTourButtonConstant.buttonWidth, height: ExitTourButtonConstant.buttonHeight)

    super.init(frame: calculatedFrame)

    frame = calculatedFrame
    layer.cornerRadius = ExitTourButtonConstant.buttonHeight * ExitTourButtonConstant.halfValue
    clipsToBounds = true
    tag = ExitGuideTourFloatingButton.tagValue

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapDetected))
    addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    backgroundColor = ExitTourButtonConstant.buttonColor

    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: bounds)

    titleLabel.text = ExitTourButtonConstant.buttonTitle
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabel.font = ExitTourButtonConstant.buttonTitleFont
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
    titleLabel.textColor = .white

    addSubview(titleLabel)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    theUnexpectedHasHappened()
}
}
```

and I'm calling it like this

```
- (void)addExitGuideTourDemoButtonView:(CGFloat)exitGuideTourButtonY

{
UIView*   exitDemoButtonView = [self getExitButtonView];

if (exitDemoButtonView == nil)
{
    exitDemoButtonView = [[ExitGuideTourFloatingButton alloc] initWithExitGuideTourButtonY:exitGuideTourButtonY];

    [self.window addSubview:exitDemoButtonView];
}
else
{
    // Do nothing
}
}


- (UIView*)getExitButtonView
{
    UIView*   exitGuideTourDemoButtonView = [self.window viewWithTag:ExitGuideTourFloatingButton.tagValue];

    return exitGuideTourDemoButtonView;
    }
```

Comment: Does this your answer? : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835333/14733292

Comment: yes I guess it is, let me check

Answer (score 0):

while you adding a button as a subview add alike

view.insertSubview(yourbutton,at index: 0)

Please refer to the below link.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622538-insertsubview

Or else you can add a button on the window.

var window :UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
window.addSubview(yourButton)

Comment: I'm currenlty adding view in window, but its not working

Comment: Try this                                                                                                                  
 guard let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate else {
            fatalError("could not get scene delegate ")
        }
        sceneDelegate.window?.addsubview

Answer (score 0):

Use bringSubviewToFront for yourButton as soon as you present the controller.

Comment: but I should need to add it on every view, isn't there a better way to achieve this ?